# Working with Types in Perl

Tags: perl, object, types

I worked with Fortran since years and with Types within Fortran of course.

Now, since I am employed at a new company, I have to work with Perl.

Since my main work is to operate with data within a text file and have to read through the file, I want to generate "objects" or "types" from this data.
In Fortran I would do that so the further work is much easier :)

Is it possible with Perl to generate types for a strict type schema like I can to it in Fortran?

For example ... this is what I would do in Fortran:

```
Type demoType
    integer i
    character(256) str
end Type
```

Then I can work with variables which are of this type. `Type(demoType) demoVar`  e.g.

Is there any chance to work like this in Perl?

Sorry for my English ... I am native German speaking :)

Comment: You should give example of the data you are working with. Just because you are used to working with types and objects does not mean its the best (or easiest!) way to work in perl.

Comment: Well i wish i could give you some data examples, but i can´t because of privacy :(

Comment: I don't *really* have to explain to you that you don't have to post real data, do I? Because that would be so tiresome.

Comment: This question reminds me of a quote from Higher Order Perl: `"A good Fortran programmer can write Fortran programs in any language"` ;)

Comment: Yeah but the problem is, that i am working with PERL the first day today and did not exactly know what is possible or not.
So why using trial n error method for a few hours, when asking PERL pro´s is faster?
So why you beeing so offensive?

Comment: @ratzeputz No, the problem is you probably asked the wrong question, because you didn't know which question to ask. So the correct way to ask, like I said from the beginning, is to describe what your data looks like. Then we can tell you how to parse it. If you don't understand perl, Class::Struct is not going to help you much.

Comment: @ratzeputz: I didn't mean to offend you at all... you asked how you can mimic Fortran types in Perl, so in a way you want to write Fortran-style programs in Perl. This is also what the quote suggests. Given your Fortran background there is nothing wrong with doing that. Perhaps you will come back to your question in a few years' time with a smile and say: "Man, I was really using a fraction of Perl's capabilities." I've been there and done that. And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: In which of my answers i wrote, that i dont understand PERL? I said that i worked with PERL today for the first time ... nothing more, nothing less. That does not mean, that i dont understand it ... it means that i dont know the benefits and how i can solve my problem on any other variant, as i would have done it in Fortran. Because i have to solve my problem quickly, the way i am used to is the best for me. I understand Class::Struct and i can work with that ... so the problem is solved.

@Zaid:
Thank you for your welcome words ... but i guess i will never feel "home" here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some CPAN modules that can help you. This is an option: [Class::Struct](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/lib/Class/Struct.pm) (which belongs to the standar perl distribution, no further installation is required). Example (taken from module documentation):

```
use Class::Struct;

struct( Rusage => {
        ru_utime => 'Timeval',  # user time used
        ru_stime => 'Timeval',  # system time used
});

struct( Timeval => [
        tv_secs  => '$',        # seconds
        tv_usecs => '$',        # microseconds
]);

# create an object:
my $t = Rusage->new(ru_utime=>Timeval->new(), ru_stime=>Timeval->new());


# $t->ru_utime and $t->ru_stime are objects of type Timeval.
# set $t->ru_utime to 100.0 sec and $t->ru_stime to 5.0 sec.
$t->ru_utime->tv_secs(100);
$t->ru_utime->tv_usecs(0);
$t->ru_stime->tv_secs(5);
$t->ru_stime->tv_usecs(0);
```

Comment: Many thanks ... that seems to be the way i am used to from my Fortran past :)

Answer (score 2):

In FORTRAN, much like C, variables mostly occupy a fixed space in memory. So a `Type` like your `demoType` describes how an item is laid out, and things like strings have to be preallocated a maximum size.

In Perl, a scalar value - mostly strings and numbers - occupies a *lot* more than just the space for the value itself, and so cannot be mapped in the same way.

To program in Perl you have to distance yourself from the implementation and allow the run time system to look after things for you. A string can vary in size indefinitely (subject to the memory of the computer) and the preferred way of associating sets of values is by using a *hash* (a type of array that is indexed by arbitrary strings instead of numbers).

For instance, a *single* `demoType` value might look like

```
my $demo_type = {
  i => 99,
  str => 'text'
}
```

and if you wanted to work with many such pairings then you should look at Perl objects.

If you have no experience of object-oriented software then you have a long and fascinating journey ahead of you!

Comment: Well i have experience in .NET ... so object-orientated is no problem. Even after many years i havent used .NET :)

Comment: Object-oriented programming in Perl is a little DIY, in that the constructor is just another method, methods are just subroutines, and you have to explicity collect and use the `this` parameter. Pretty much all Perl provides is encapsulation via packages and inheritance and polymorphism using `bless` and a method call syntax introduced in Perl 5.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_a4.pdf).
If you want to work with types, then look at Moose to work in an object-oriented way and expose methods and attributes.
The core perl is dynamically evaluation a variable to assign a type to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be trying to store the integer value, and the stringified value of the same number.

```
{
  i = 123;
  str = "123";
}
```

If that is the case, you are trying to do something that Perl does automatically for you.

```
my $integer = 123;

my $string = $integer;

print $string;
```

---

Another possibility is that you need to associate a number with a string. In which case you can just use:

- an array.

  ```
  my @data = ( 123, 'string' );

  print 'integer: ', $data[0], "\n";
  print 'string: ', $data[1], "\n";
  ```
- an array ref.

  ```
  my $data = [ 123, 'string' ];

  print 'integer: ', $data->[0], "\n";
  print 'string: ', $data->[1], "\n";
  ```
- a hash

  ```
  my %data = (
    123 => 'string',
  );

  print $data{123}, "\n";
  ```
- a hash ref

  ```
  my $data = {
    123 => 'string',
  };

  print $data->{123}, "\n";
  ```

---

At any rate you should really post anonymized example data, so that we can actually help you to learn Perl.

I think you should read the [documentation for Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org). It is quite [extensive](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html). It is actually how I learned to program in Perl.

At the very least read [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) and [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html). If you need to build nested data structures you should also have a look at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

You could also look at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org).